# GORM SQL Optimization

Tags: sql, go, grails-orm, go-gorm

Here i am usign GORM for sql query.
I have declared the models. the thing is I need output like these.
I am able to generate expected output but it takes for loop so i think we can optimize the query performance by reducing the nested calls. so how can i merge this query kind of sub or nested query.

```
type Result struct {
    User1 User1
    User2 User2
}
type User1 struct {
    User     string
    Query_id string  `gorm:"primary_key"json:"query_id"`
    User2    []User2 `gorm:"foreignkey:query_id" json:"input"`
}
type User2 struct {
    Table_name string `json:"table_name"`
    Query_id   string `gorm:"primary_key"json:"query_id"`
}
func (User2) TableName() string {
    return "tabledata"
}
func (User1) TableName() string {
    return "querydata"
}
var user1 User1
var user2 []User2
db.Find(&user2)
db.Select("querydata.query_id,querydata.user,tabledata.table_name").Joins("JOIN tabledata ON tabledata.query_id = querydata.query_id ").Find(&user1)
user1.User2 = user2
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"result": &user1})
```

**current output:**

```
  "result": {
    "User": "ram",
    "query_id": "firstquery",
    "input": [
      {
        "table_name": "first_table",
        "query_id": "firstquery"
      },
      {
        "table_name": "second_table",
        "query_id": "firstquery"
      },
      {
        "table_name": "second_table",
        "query_id": "secondquery"
      },
      {
        "table_name": "second_table",
        "query_id": "secondquery"
      }]
}

**Expected output**

"result": 
{
    "User": "ram",
    "query_id": "firstquery",
    "input": [
      {
        "table_name": "first_table",
        "query_id": "firstquery"
      },
      {
        "table_name": "second_table",
        "query_id": "firstquery"
      }]

},
{
    "User": "krishna",
    "query_id": "secondquery",
    "input": [
      {
        "table_name": "first_table",
        "query_id": "secondquery"
      },
      {
        "table_name": "second_table",
        "query_id": "secondquery"
      }]

}
}


**Expected output via this**
I am able to generate expected output through this, but I want to minimize this for loop calls. so any suggestion how can I improve GROM SQL . 

var qresult []User1
db.Table("qtb").Find(&qresult)
for i := range qresult {
db.Table("ttb").Select("table_name").Where("query_id=?", qresult[i].Query_id).Find(&qresult[i].User2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should preload `User2` in your query:

```golang
var qresult []User1
db.Preload("tabledata").Find(&qresult)
```